# How to add content to Vuetify (v-navigation-drawer)

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I found this codepen: https://codepen.io/carl_/pen/QWwgqBa, which closely does as  I want.
But there is no content/text on the right side.
And I cant figure out how to add content on the right side.

I have tried to google the problem and found solutions like "add v-content", "it needs to be inside v-app". But none of these actually got the content on the right side. It ended below the card or inside the navigation-drawer.

How can I manage to get content on the right side of the menu?

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card style="width:800px;margin:40px auto">
      <v-navigation-drawer
        expand-on-hover
        permanent
      >
        <template v-slot:prepend>
          <v-list>
            <v-list-item>
              <v-list-item-avatar>
                <v-img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/85.jpg"></v-img>
              </v-list-item-avatar>
            </v-list-item>

            <v-list-item
              link
              two-line
            >
              <v-list-item-content>
                <v-list-item-title class="title">Sandra Adams</v-list-item-title>
                <v-list-item-subtitle>sandra_a88@gmail.com</v-list-item-subtitle>
              </v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-action>
                <v-icon>mdi-menu-down</v-icon>
              </v-list-item-action>
            </v-list-item>
          </v-list>
        </template>

        <v-divider></v-divider>

        <v-list
          nav
          dense
        >
          <v-list-item link>
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-folder</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title>My Files</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item link>
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-account-multiple</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title>Shared with me</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
          <v-list-item link>
            <v-list-item-icon>
              <v-icon>mdi-star</v-icon>
            </v-list-item-icon>
            <v-list-item-title>Starred</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list>
      </v-navigation-drawer>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: <v-layout> was the attribute I needed to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<v-layout>` was the attribute I needed to add.